# Creating a matrix in a structure

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I am trying to create a structure that will have two integer values, an array, and two 2-D matrices using my code below. I can initialize the structure with the integers and array just fine, and my 'Gen' function will create the random values I want for the array.

However, when I try adding in the matrix components, I run into a problem. My compiler gives me a warning: "initialization from incompatible pointer type". If I understand what I have read so far, this is because the structure needs to be pointed to an array of pointers that represent each row in the matrix. I don't know the syntax for that.

A quick note: the other topics I've seen that are related to this issue all initialize the structure in a function other than the main() function, so I haven't found those solutions helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define structure
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    int *arr;
    int **mat1;
    int **mat2;
}container;


// Function headers 
void Gen(container Thing);


int main() {

    int row = 5;
    int col = 6;
    int A[row];
    int M1[row][col];
    int M2[row][col+1];

    // Initialize structure
    container Object = {row, col, A, M1, M2};

    // Run "Gen" function
    Gen(Object);

    int i, j; // Index variables

    // Display the array
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", Object.arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    // Display the numbers from the matrices
    for(j = 0; j < Object.row; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < Object.col; i++)
        {
            printf("%i ", Object.mat1[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(j = 0; j < Object.row; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < Object.col; i++)
        {
            printf("%i ", Object.mat2[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Function to generate random values in the array & matrices
void Gen(container Thing)
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Generate random values for the array
    for(i = 0; i < Thing.row; i++)
    {
        Thing.arr[i] = rand() % 5;
    }

    // Generate random values for the matrix
    for(j = 0; j < Thing.row; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < Thing.col; i++)
        {
            Thing.mat1[j][i] = rand() % 5;
            Thing.mat2[j][i] = rand() % 5;
        }
    } 
} // End of "Gen" function
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO with that error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=initialization+from+incompatible+pointer+type

Comment: There is no array in your `struct`, only pointers. A pointer is not the same as an array and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
container Object = {row, col, A, M1, M2};
```

is wrong since the type of `M1` is `int[row][col]`, which can decay to `int (*)[col]` but not to `int**`. You have the same problem with `M2`.

You'll need to rethink your strategy for generating a `container`.

For example:

```
int main() {

   int row = 5;
   int col = 6;
   int A[row];
   int* M1[row];
   int* M2[row];

   for ( int i = 0; i < row; ++i )
   {
      M1[i] = malloc(sizeof(M1[i][0])*col);
      M2[i] = malloc(sizeof(M1[i][0])*(col+1));
   }

   // Initialize structure
   container Object = {row, col, A, M1, M2};


   ...


   for ( int i = 0; i < row; ++i )
   {
      free(M1[i]);
      free(M2[i]);
   }

   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```